How to create unit tests for MAUI hybrid app?
I am working on a MAUI Hybrid app, and I want to add unit tests for it. At first it was a regular MAUI app. I was able to create a xUnit test project for it. The csproj looked like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
....

Now using this kind of project for a MAUI Hybrid app does not work:

Project is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0).
Project supports:

net8.0-android34.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
net8.0-ios17.5 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
net8.0-maccatalyst17.5 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
net8.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)

Project targets
'net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst;net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets
'.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0'

Unfortunately there are no info out there regarding MAUI hybrid project, only regular MAUI project so I have not found guidance.
-> How to create a xUnit project (is that possible in a first place, if not which kind of unit test project work ?) for MAUI Hybrid ?
Thanks for any help with this

Please try the following steps,
1.Change your MAUI csproj, add net8.0 to TargetFrameworks
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>

2.Still in MAUI csproj:
Replace
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

with
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>

For more info, you may refer to the MauixUnitTestSample sample code and  Unit Testing tutorial.

Thanks for your reponse, indeed I forgot to add .net8.0 to the TargetFrameworks. Unfortunately doing this now prevents the app from compiling when running Tests. I get the following error: error MSB4057: The target "GetTargetPath" does not exist in the project.

Do you use a default template? Is the Visual Studio up-to-date?

My bad I got things mixed up at some point. If anybody comes here with the same issue make sure you do add net8.0 to your app csproj as well, and the "OutputType Condition" as well:
net8.0;net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst
Exe
Thanks again for your help
